# How do determine "if time is less than x" inside a django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am currently working on an inbox using Django-Messages.  Right now when I go to the inbox, it lists all messages, but what I'm trying to do is organize the messages into blocks on the page, by today, yesterday, last week, ect.  I currently have a for loop that iterates through all the messages and displays them.  I would imagine I need to nest an if statement inside the for loop, maybe like so:

```
Inbox | Received Today
{% if message.date - current.date < 24 hours %}
   Sent by: {{ message.sender }}
   {{ message.body }}
{% elif message.date - current.date > 24 hours and message.date - current.date < 48 hours %}
   Sent by: {{ message.sender }}
   {{ message.body }

{% endif %}
```

My question is what do I put for "current.date"?  I am aware that I can find the current date in python by doing:

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

but how can I get this within the template?  Do i need to do this within the views first and then use the variable inside the template?

I also feel like the way I'm trying to do this might not be all that efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a template filter to use in the template.

Inside your app directory create a directory called `templatetags`, then inside that directory create a file called `messages_tags.py` (you can name it whatever you want)

The body of `messages_tags.py` should be as follows:

```
# Use datetime if not localizing timezones
import datetime
# Otherwise use timezone
from django.utils import timezone 

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def hours_ago(time, hours):
    return time + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours) < datetime.datetime.now() # or timezone.now() if your time is offset-aware
```

Now your template becomes:

```
{% load messages_tags %}

Inbox | Received Today
{% if message.date|hours_ago:24 %}
   Sent by: {{ message.sender }}
   {{ message.body }}
{% elif message.date|hours_ago:48 %}
   Sent by: {{ message.sender }}
   {{ message.body }

{% endif %}
```

You may need to manually restart your server for django to recognize the new template tags.

Also see that you don't need to check in the elif that message.date is more than 24 hours, because if it was less than 24 hours the first `if` would be executed and the `elif` would not even be considered.

You could also use days, or any other time value recognized by datetime to check how long ago a message was. Hours may get messy if you're checking back a long time.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  I am still new to Django but template filters seems really awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: I am getting "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'".  I also imported datetime.timedelta just to be safe.

Comment: That would mean that the time being passed to the filter is `None` (i.e. message.date = None). Would you expect `message.date` ever to be null?

Comment: stupid mistake I mispelled date...  i've fixed that now I'm getting TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: I'm going to make a new post

Comment: If you are trying to use `timezone.now()` use `datetime.datetime.now()` instead, and if you are using `datetime.datetime.now()` use `timezone.now()`. This should fix the problem

Comment: That error has to do with the way Python handles TimeZones in datetimes. DateTimes can either be offset-aware, which means that they have the tzinfo attribute specified, or offset-naive, which means that they don't. The error that you are getting is from trying to compare an offset-aware datetime with an offset-naive datetime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539281/how-can-i-print-the-date-received-only-one-time-while-using-a-for-loop